# PostGIS layer in GeoServer

Tags: postgis, geoserver, amazon-ec2

I am attempting to create a web map in OpenLayers by pulling in layers from GeoServer which is running on an Amazon EC2 instance.  The prepackaged layers from GeoServer seem to show up fine when I substitute their URL in the map code. However I have a PostGIS layer that I am wanting to use as the basis for the map which is not showing up no matter what I try.

I have read several threads that seem to indicate it's a problem with mismatched projections. But I'm not sure where or how to "reproject" the layer or if that is my problem. It does shows up in the GeoServer OpenLayers preview (as a single tile, but not "tiled" for some reason). The declared SRS when I originally published the layer in GeoServer is EPSG:404000. I'm not sure why it is that. Changing it doesn't seem to help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Tiled WMS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.4/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <!-- The line below is only needed for old environments like Internet Explorer and Android 4.x -->
    <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>
    <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.4/build/ol.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script>
      var layers = [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
          extent: [-13884991, 2870341, -7455066, 6338219],
          source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
            url: 'http://ec2-18-221-107-236.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/geoserver/Prospect1/wms',
            params: {'LAYERS': 'prospect_leases', 'TILED': true},
            serverType: 'geoserver',
            isBaseLayer: false,
            projection: 'EPSG:404000'
          })
        })
      ];
      var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: layers,
        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({
          center: ol.proj.transform([-97.3311, 33.0649], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
          zoom: 16
        })
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How is the data being served by GeoServer, is it WMS, WCS, WFS, or something else? What  is your PostGIS data?

Comment: The postgis layer is a shapefile. It is being served up as a WMS

Comment: I should have said can you edit the question to add those details (still applies :) I don't think you can hold a shapefile in PostGIS just import one.  So what command did you use to load the data, does it honour the projection of the shapefile

Comment: Sorry I should have added that. I uploaded the shapefile to postgres, also on an Amazon instance (RDS).

Comment: How did you add the shapefile to postgis?

Answer (score 2):

I finally did figure this out. I had not actually declared a coordinate system in the SRIS field of the PostGIS shapefile importer/loader.

Answer (score 1):

> The declared SRS when I originally published the layer in GeoServer is
>   EPSG:404000.

I suspect it's still an SRS issue, according to http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/7589/, it's a `2D wildcard coordinate reference system in meters`. The WKT for the SRS does not show much useful information (e.g. datum is unknown...):

> LOCAL_CS["Wildcard 2D cartesian plane in metric 
>   unit",LOCAL_DATUM["Unknown",0],UNIT["m",1.0],AXIS["x",EAST],AXIS["y",NORTH],AUTHORITY["EPSG","404000"]]

Maybe you can load the PostGIS layer in QGIS first and see if it aligns well with any other layer with well-defined SRS (e.g. WGS84).